# CNContactPickerViewController and Android Contact Picker - Switch to Single or multiple contacts

Tags: android, swift, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm developing a contact search module for a xamarin forms app. I use dependency injection to launch native contact pickers. The search function has four filters.

- OnlyEmail
  contact must have at least one email address.
- OnlyPhoneNumber
  contact must have at least one phone number.
- EmailOrPhoneNumber
  contact must have at least an email address or a phone number.
- EmailAndPhoneNumber
  contact must have at least one email address and a phone number.

Following is my Xamarin.ios code.

```
public async Task<List<CNContact>> LaunchContact(IViewContext context, ContactsSearch contactsSearch)
    {
        List<CNContact> contactsList = new List<CNContact>();

        CNContactPickerViewController contactPickerViewController = new CNContactPickerViewController();

        var emailPredicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat("emailAddresses.@count > 0");
        var phoneNumbersPredicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat("phoneNumbers.@count > 0");

        var compoundPredicate = new List<NSPredicate>();

        switch (contactsSearch.SearchOption)
        {
            case SearchOption.OnlyEmail:
                compoundPredicate.Add(emailPredicate);
                break;
            case SearchOption.OnlyPhoneNumber:
                compoundPredicate.Add(phoneNumbersPredicate);
                break;
            case SearchOption.EmailOrPhoneNumber:
                compoundPredicate.Add(NSPredicate.FromFormat("emailAddresses.@count > 0 OR phoneNumbers.@count > 0"));
                break;
            case SearchOption.EmailAndPhoneNumber:
                compoundPredicate.Add(emailPredicate);
                compoundPredicate.Add(phoneNumbersPredicate);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        var predicateListCount = compoundPredicate.Count;

        if (predicateListCount > 0)
        {
            var compoundPredicateArray = new NSPredicate[predicateListCount];
            for (int index = 0; index < predicateListCount; index++)
            {
                compoundPredicateArray[index] = compoundPredicate[index];
            }
            contactPickerViewController.PredicateForEnablingContact =
                NSCompoundPredicate.CreateAndPredicate(compoundPredicateArray);
        }


        TaskCompletionSource<List<CNContact>> promise = new TaskCompletionSource<List<CNContact>>();
        bool contactPickerPresented = false;

        try
        {
            var displayWaitingIndicator = WaitingIndicator.IsWaitingIndicatorVisible;
            var currentContext = ((PageRenderer)context.Renderer);


            contactPickerViewController.PredicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate.FromValue(true);
            contactPickerViewController.Delegate = new ContactPickerDelegate(promise);

            contactPickerViewController.DisplayedPropertyKeys = KeysToFetch;

            if (displayWaitingIndicator)
            {
                await WaitingIndicator.HideWaitingIndicatorAsync(true);
            }
            currentContext.PresentViewController(contactPickerViewController, true, null);
            contactPickerPresented = true;

            if (displayWaitingIndicator)
            {
                await WaitingIndicator.ShowWaitingIndicatorAsync();
            }
            contactsList = await promise.Task;
            if (contactsList.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            if (contactPickerViewController != null && contactPickerPresented)
            {
                contactPickerViewController.DismissModalViewController(true);
            }
        }

        return contactsList;
    }
```

I implemented CNContactPickerDelegate for this.

Following is my Xamarin.android code

```
public async Task<ICursor> LaunchContact(IViewContext context, ContactsSearch contactsSearch)
    {
        var currentActivity = (Activity)((PageRenderer)context.Renderer).Context;
        var contentResolver = currentActivity.ContentResolver;
        var promise = new TaskCompletionSource<ICursor>();
        var type = string.Empty;

        switch (contactsSearch.SearchOption)
        {
            case SearchOption.OnlyEmail:

                type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentType;
                break;

            case SearchOption.OnlyPhoneNumber:
                type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentType;
                break;

            case SearchOption.EmailOrPhoneNumber:
                break;

            case SearchOption.EmailAndPhoneNumber:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        ContactsActivity.ContactsPickerPromise = promise;

        var contactsActivityIntent = new Intent(currentActivity, typeof(ContactsActivity));
        contactsActivityIntent.PutExtra(ContactsActivity.INTENT_TYPE_KEY, type);
        currentActivity.StartActivity(contactsActivityIntent);

        ICursor selectedContactsCursor = await promise.Task;

        return selectedContactsCursor;
    }
```

**ContactsActivity**

```
public class ContactsActivity : Activity
{

    private const int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<ICursor> promise;
    public static TaskCompletionSource<ICursor> ContactsPickerPromise { get; set; }
    public const string IntentExtraContext = "ActivityContext";
    public const string INTENT_TYPE_KEY = "CONTACT_PICKER_URL_INTENT";

    public ContactsActivity()
    {
        promise = ContactsPickerPromise;
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LaunchContactPicker();
    }

    private void LaunchContactPicker()
    {
        var contactPickerType = Intent.GetStringExtra(INTENT_TYPE_KEY);
        var contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);
        if (contactPickerType != "")
        {
            contactPickerIntent.SetType(contactPickerType);
        }
        else
        {
            contactPickerIntent.SetData(ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);
        }


        StartActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Finish();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Result.Ok)
                {
                    Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
                    var contentResolver = this.ContentResolver;
                    var contactsCursor = contentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                    promise.TrySetResult(contactsCursor);
                }
                else
                {
                    promise.TrySetCanceled();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                promise.SetException(ex);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The result of the codes are as following.

Android contact picker launches with filtered contacts but only allows to select one email or phone number. If the contacts are filtered by email its phone number can't be picked and vice versa.

iOS contact picker view controller shows all the contacts but the contacts that don't match a given criteria are greyed out and not pickable. Multiple selection is available and all the details of selected contacts are visible.

My question is can Android contact picker be set to select multiple contacts and if yes, How to switch between selecting a single contact and multiple contacts?

EDIT - Found a workaround to select/deselect multiple contacts selection in iOS. 
You only have to implement two CNContactPickerDelegate classes. One for DidSelectContact() method and the other for DidSelectContacts() method. Only thing left is to find a way to enable multiple selection in Android contact picker.

Comment: You could refer to: http://sachindotg.blogspot.com/2013/11/android-simple-multi-contacts-picker.html

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT This is a custom picker, which requires read contacts permission. Do you know how to do it with the native picker? Or if it's not possible, any valid documentation to back it up?

Comment: [Requesting Runtime Permissions in Android 5.0+](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)

Comment: [Permissions Plugin for Xamarin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)

Comment: I went through them. But I'm looking for a way to filter data with the native picker.